# Scrapy crawl not following spider name

Tags: python, scrapy

Having an issue running scrapy spider.
I have 3 spider files, 1 of which I do not use, looks something like this.
spider1
spider2
spider3

I had 1 main spider (spider1) for a while now worked well, decided to add another spider (spider3) I just made a new .py file with a proper name. Been working on building the 2nd spider for a while, got everything working as it should.
Now my issue is running the 1st spider.
When I do  `scrapy scraw spider1` it just runs 3rd spider, and I know everything is named correctly.
I tried running `scrapy list` it just start running 3rd spider. I run `scrapy version` it just runs 3rd spider. If I run `scrapy crawl RandomName` it also just runs 3rd spider.
I tried deleting all the `__pycahe__` files still same result.
I tried to uninstall and reinstall on scrapy still the same result.

Is there something I need to do in `settings.py` for it to not ignore spider name in the `scrapy crawl` command, or other commands for that matter?

I don't need to run 2 spider at the same time or 1 after another, I just want to `scrapy crawl` to listen to the spider I am trying to call.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get the best result on Stack Overflow, see how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to paste the code maybe you have some project structure and miss files locations ?